# Recommended open source java mailing list software

Tags: java, open-source, mailing-list

Can anyone recommend a based open source mailing list software ?

The following would all be desired if possible:

- Java as the underlying language, as we have people who are experienced with Java
- Something which is packaged as a war and can be dropped into a Tomcat server
- A sleek interface
- Underlying data should be reasonably transparent
- Good support for groups - sometimes we want to send mail to everyone, sometimes only people working in a certain area etc.

This is for a non-profit tax-payer funded research organization, so open-source (free) is a high priority. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://subetha.tigris.org/

Comment: Moved to Google Code, moved to Github https://github.com/voodoodyne/subetha

Answer (score 2):

Apache James http://james.apache.org/server/2.3.2/mailing_lists.html