# Open source mailing list software with web services

Tags: java, php, mailing-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recommended open source java mailing list software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780357/recommended-open-source-java-mailing-list-software)

Can anyone recommend open source mailing list software that I can install onto my web server? I am looking for the following capabilities:

- Accessible via web services (SOAP, REST, etc.)
- GUI web-based management console
- Supports MySQL database

Ideally, I'd like for the software to be PHP or Java. So far, I have found [phpList](http://www.phplist.com/) and [Sympa](http://www.sympa.org/).

phpList looks great, but falls short with no web services support. Sympa isn't bad, it supports SOAP but it is written in Python.

Thanks!

Comment: I viewed that post before creating my own. It's not a duplicate, as I have listed different requirements.

Comment: I just linked it for historical reference. By your question your own it's likely a candidate for not being constructive. Stackoverflow is not a I need this tool, here are my requirements, tell me what's great kind of questions does work well. I can understand that you would like to have some helping hands with your research, maybe somebody can shed more light into this for you, but you should create a better list in parallel. Do a table of exising tools and which of your requirements they fulfil.

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I can make something more constructive.